# Why doesn't Kylo Ren sense that Han Solo is standing behind him?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-force, kylo-ren

At this point Kylo Ren has already sensed Han's presence on Starkiller Base. When Kylo is on the bridge, Han is standing a stone's throw away from him, yet Kylo doesn't sense him there and Han has to yell to get his attention. Is sensing through the Force so imprecise that even when someone you're looking for is standing in close proximity you still only have a vague feeling that they're somewhere on the planet?!

Comment: wasnt he bleeding out at that time from all the abuse rey and fin did to him? he would have been to angry to focus properly. also Kylo is the newest adition to the Disneys stable of Princesses so meh.

Comment: Even if he sensed Han behind him, it still makes perfect sense to keep walking to the middle of the bridge; he needed Han to come out from his hiding place and join him on the bridge where there's much less chance of Han escaping/hiding when the conversation takes a turn for the worst. :(

Comment: @RedCaio That's actually a very interesting thought. Debatable, but definitely original and worth thinking about - sounds like it should be an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @Cherubel no, Kylo Ren confronts Han first, _then_ confronts Rey and Finn in the forest. :)

Answer (score 4):

Despite their close familial link, Han proved difficult for Ren to track because he was **intentionally concealing his presence in the Force** by exercising strong control over his thoughts and emotions.

> Here, Ren told himself with increasing certainty. He is here. Raising
> his gaze, he focused on one support column out of many. Slowly he
> advanced toward it, prepared for whatever might ensue.
> Nothing did. There was no one behind the column.
>
> ...
>
> Rising from his hiding place, Han looked back the way he had come. **If
> he left now and managed to control his thoughts and emotions while
> retracing his steps, there was a good chance he could make it out of
> the building.** If he was really lucky, he would be able to slip outside
> without drawing the attention of any searching stormtroopers — or anyone
> else.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

It would seem that although Han has all the Force ability of a turnip, *mental concealment* isn't actually a Force talent and is evidently something that can be mastered by a non-Jedi.